# How to get screen width and height in motorola milestone, android

Tags: android

I have used the followng ways to get screen width and height. When I run my application in motorola I got width= 320pixel and height = 533 pixel. But size of motorla milestone is 480 x 854 pixels. How to get height as 854 and width as 480
see http://www.gsmarena.com/motorola_milestone-3001.php

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay(); 
int width = display.getWidth();
int height = display.getHeight();

DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);

int heightOfScreen = metrics.heightPixels;
int widthOfScreen = metrics.widthPixels;
System.out.println("...w1..."+width+"...h1..."+height+"....w2...."+widthOfScreen+"...h2..."+heightOfScreen);
```

**Output**
    w1=320...h1=533...w2=320...h2=533

Comment: The reason you were seeing 320x533 and not 480x854 is because you're in Donut compatibility mode. Setting your `targetSdkVersion` to something >= 4 should fix it. Compatibility mode basically forces your app into thinking it's running on an HVGA-like phone, for compatibility with pre-1.6 versions of the OS. Thus, pixel coordinates are scaled down to 2/3 real pixels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried with the following approach. It worked for me.

```
WindowManager windowManager = (WindowManager) activity.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
int height = windowManager.getDefaultDisplay().getHeight();
int width = windowManager.getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();
```

Answer (score 2):

I have not tried this, but from what you have tried so far I'm willing to bet this will work:

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
float width = metrics.widthPixels * metrics.xdpi;
float height = metrics.heightPixels * metrics.ydpi;
```

**Edit**: you can also try [`Display.getSize`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Display.html#getSize%28android.graphics.Point%29).

**Second edit**: scratch that. My first solution is incorrect and my second solution is API Level 13+ only. However, I have tried both your methods and they worked correctly on a [Huawei Ideos X5](http://www.gsmarena.com/huawei_u8800_ideos_x5-3596.php) (Android 2.2) and a [Nexus S](http://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_google_nexus_s_i9023-3910.php) (Android 2.3.4). It might just be Motorola's fault here. Are there any official updates available for your phone's OS?

Comment: It didnt work for me. i got width = 51200.o and height = 85280.0

Comment: I am informing you what is the result i got

Comment: As I said in my (edited) answer, I think it's a problem with your specific device. Both your methods of getting the screen width / height have worked for me on two different devices and OS versions.

Comment: you mean to say whether this is the issue with motorolla milestone?

Comment: I have also tested both methods on a HTC Hero 2.1 and they work fine.

Comment: @Adinia, As i have mentioned in my question. I am getting this issue in motorola milestone

Comment: @Deepakkk I know, I just wanted to confirm Felix answer; and maybe you should change your question title, to be more specific.

Comment: @Adinia, I have edited the question you can have a look on that. I think it is more specific now